# Persistent error with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to have a table that uses the entire page width in 3 columns and use a bullet point in each item. I came up with the following code

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y Y Y}

$\bullet$ Item A & $\bullet$ Item B & $\bullet$ Item C \\
\end{tabularx}
```

However every time I compile it, I get a series of erros on the same line, as shown in the attached picture.

[image: Problem]

Here is a minimum example that reproduces the error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\left\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,267mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y Y Y}

    $\bullet$ Item A & $\bullet$ Item B & $\bullet$ Item C \\


\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us a mwe (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us how the `Y` column type is defined.

Comment: Hi guys, just edited the post to reply your comments

Comment: What's the `\left` doing in the definition of `Y`?

Comment: If you want to have left alignment, then `\raggedright` is the command to use, not `\left`, which is a command for math material.

Comment: Thank you egreg, worked perfectly. The reason I was using \left is because I'm new to latex and know very little about it yet. Living and learning, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to make columns with left alignment, then do

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
```

The command `\left` has a completely different meaning.